# Split scrapped table into lists with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, list, web-scraping, scrape

So I have a basic 3 lines here.  Gives me the info I want when I print airlines[3] but if I put it in a for loop like 'for i in airlines[3]:' it only prints out Airlines and Destinations.  I want to take all the airlines put them into their own list and I want all the destinations in their own list too.

```
import pandas as pd
airlines = pd.read_html('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tan_Son_Nhat_International_Airport')

# Prints off table
print(airlines[3])


airlines_list = []
destination_list = []
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`airlines[3]` is a pandas dataframe. Use below commands to create separate lists:

```
In [1606]: df = airlines[3]

In [1607]: airlines_list = df['Airlines'].tolist()

In [1609]: destination_list = df['Destinations'].tolist()
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to not consider duplicates in either of those list , you can use `set()`

```
list(set(df['Destinations']))
```